network simulator3で各ノードのキュー長を取得する方法について．
現在ns-3でVANET(車車間通信)シミュレーションを実装していますが，各車両のパケットキューのキュー長を一定時間毎に取得する方法が分かりません．
ご教授頂けると幸いです．
network simulator3のバージョンは3.38です．
